# ASP.Net - Mathematic operations and percentages - VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a table as below which I am populating with the number of 'Pass' and 'Fail' records in each column. I am then trying to work out the failure rate for each column and an average failure rate for the 3 'IR Room' devices and the 3 'Employee Exit' devices.

[image: Table]

I am populating the labels using the code at the bottom of this post, however I have 2 issues:-

1. I am getting an 'Input string was not in the correct format' error
   on line 86 (Dim irAverageFailureRate as String)
2. I cannot help but think there is a better way to do this. I'm
   new to ASP/VB so any advice on how to improve this would be
   gratefully received.

   ```
   Sub getYesterdayStats()

   Dim con As OleDbConnection
   Dim cmdClockings As OleDbDataAdapter
   Dim dsClockings As New DataSet
   Dim yesterday As String = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")


   con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; DATA SOURCE=\\XXX.XX.XXX.XX\XXXX.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=XXXXX;")
   cmdClockings = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT efrLog.PID, efrLog.LType, efrLog.LDName from efrLog WHERE LDate = '" & yesterday & "'", con)

   cmdClockings.Fill(dsClockings, "Clockings")

   ' Get pass and fail count for each device
   Dim ir1Pass As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'PASS' AND LDName = 'IR Room 1'").Count
   Dim ir1Fail As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'DENY' AND LDName = 'IR Room 1'").Count
   Dim ir2Pass As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'PASS' AND LDName = 'IR Room 2'").Count
   Dim ir2Fail As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'DENY' AND LDName = 'IR Room 2'").Count
   Dim ir3Pass As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'PASS' AND LDName = 'IR Room 3'").Count
   Dim ir3Fail As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'DENY' AND LDName = 'IR Room 3'").Count
   Dim ee1Pass As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'PASS' AND LDName = 'Employee Exit 1'").Count
   Dim ee1Fail As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'DENY' AND LDName = 'Employee Exit 1'").Count
   Dim ee2Pass As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'PASS' AND LDName = 'Employee Exit 2'").Count
   Dim ee2Fail As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'DENY' AND LDName = 'Employee Exit 2'").Count
   Dim ee3Pass As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'PASS' AND LDName = 'Employee Exit 3'").Count
   Dim ee3Fail As Integer = dsClockings.Tables("Clockings").Select("LType = 'DENY' AND LDName = 'Employee Exit 3'").Count

   ' Calculate totals for each device
   Dim ir1total As Integer = ir1Pass + ir1Fail
   Dim ir2total As Integer = ir2Pass + ir2Fail
   Dim ir3total As Integer = ir3Pass + ir3Fail
   Dim ee1total As Integer = ee1Pass + ee1Fail
   Dim ee2total As Integer = ee2Pass + ee2Fail
   Dim ee3total As Integer = ee3Pass + ee3Fail

   ' Calcualte failure rate for each device
   Dim ir1failureRate As String = Format((ir1Fail / ir1Pass) * 100, "0.00")
   Dim ir2failureRate As String = Format((ir2Fail / ir2Pass) * 100, "0.00")
   Dim ir3failureRate As String = Format((ir3Fail / ir3Pass) * 100, "0.00")
   Dim ee1failureRate As String = Format((ee1Fail / ee1Pass) * 100, "0.00")
   Dim ee2failureRate As String = Format((ee2Fail / ee2Pass) * 100, "0.00")
   Dim ee3failureRate As String = Format((ee3Fail / ee3Pass) * 100, "0.00")

   ' Calculate average failure rate for IR and EE devices
   Dim irAverageFailureRate As String = Format((Format((ir1Fail / ir1Pass) * 100, "0.00") + Format((ir2Fail / ir2Pass) * 100, "0.00") + Format((ir3Fail / ir3Pass) * 100, "0.00")) / 3, "0.00")
   Dim eeAverageFailureRate As String = Format((Format((ee1Fail / ee1Pass) * 100, "0.00") + Format((ee2Fail / ee2Pass) * 100, "0.00") + Format((ee3Fail / ee3Pass) * 100, "0.00")) / 3, "0.00")

   ' Assign values to labels
   lblIR1pass.Text = ir1Pass
   lblIR1fail.Text = ir1Fail
   lblIR2pass.Text = ir2Pass
   lblIR2fail.Text = ir2Fail
   lblIR3pass.Text = ir3Pass
   lblIR3fail.Text = ir3Fail
   lblEE1pass.Text = ee1Pass
   lblEE1fail.Text = ee1Fail
   lblEE2pass.Text = ee2Pass
   lblEE2fail.Text = ee2Fail
   lblEE3pass.Text = ee3Pass
   lblEE3fail.Text = ee3Fail
   lblIR1tot.Text = ir1total
   lblIR2tot.Text = ir2total
   lblIR3tot.Text = ir3total
   lblEE1tot.Text = ee1total
   lblEE2tot.Text = ee2total
   lblEE3tot.Text = ee3total
   lblIR1fr.Text = ir1failureRate & "%"
   lblIR2fr.Text = ir2failureRate & "%"
   lblIR3fr.Text = ir3failureRate & "%"
   lblEE1fr.Text = ee1failureRate & "%"
   lblEE2fr.Text = ee2failureRate & "%"
   lblEE3fr.Text = ee3failureRate & "%"
   lblIRafr.Text = irAverageFailureRate & "%"
   lblEEafr.Text = eeAverageFailureRate & "%"
   ```

   End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of unnecessary Formats in that line.

```
Dim irAverageFailureRate As String = ((CDbl(ir1Fail) / ir1Pass) + (CDbl(ir2Fail) / ir2Pass) + (CDbl(ir3Fail) / ir3Pass) / 3).ToString("P")
```

I got the "P" for percentage from [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this solved the error problem, however it was returning an incorrect average calculation. I trimmed it down slightly to do the totals then did the average in a separate sum using the below code, however I am unsure how to format this to 2 decimal places. It currently formats to 13. Any ideas? Thanks

`Dim irAverageFailureRate As String = String.Format(CDbl(irTotalFailureRate / 2), "P")`

Comment: @Jimsan Oops, that was a silly error on my part. It should have been .ToString("P") at the end, like this: `Dim irAverageFailureRate As String = (CDbl(irTotalFailureRate) / 2).ToString("P")`